# How does the Monte Carlo method work in event generators?

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

I was reading about event generators (usually NuWro and GENIE) and saw that cross-sections are obtained for the neutrino-nucleon interactions in Quasi-Elastic, Deep Inelastic Current and Neutral Charged phenomena, etc., 
but what exactly do the Monte Carlo method?
What does it simulate?
What part of the process physics is contained in this method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internals of either of those programs, so the following comments are rather general (and based on my own experience with more specialized event generators;
including one written from scratch from first-principles and couple I've debugged and improved).

---

The calculation of cross-sections generaly requires that you compute several things

- A matrix element that depends on the exchanged four-momentum
- A phase space for the products.
- Depending on the application, you may want to do initial- and final-state corrections.
- Cosmic ray generators will generally start with an approximation to empirical distribution for the incident particle flux. Beam experiments also have distributions functions for the incident particles, but they are less wide-ranging.

The matrix element is usually a straight forward calculation with the right inputs.

The phase-space is an integral over a region in the out-going configuration space with complicated boundaries, and computing integrals is one of the main strengths of Monte Carlo methods.

The corrections (if desired) are selected from a propoerly weighed distributions which means more random numbers. However, they affect the inputs that should be used for the matrix element.